# Powershell truncated output

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am currently running a simple script which is intended to retrieve all the mailboxes a user has access to.  My problem is that the first column (Identity) is being truncated and hence I cannot see the mailbox name.
I tried various options such as -AutoSize, changing the $FormatEnumerationLimit =-1 to no avail.

Script:-

```
$FormatEnumerationLimit =-1
Add-PSSnapin *Microsoft.Exchange*
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -User username | Out-File C:\temp\test.txt
```

Result:-

```
Identity         User            AccessRights      IsInherited  Deny
---------        ----            ------------      -----------  ----

domain/Mai...    DOMAIN\username {FullAccess}       False       False
```

Comment: instead of exporting to a plain text file, use `Export-CSV` to give you a structured file. if you MUST have a nearly useless plain text file [*grin*], use `Format-Table` and the `-AutoSize` parameter OR add the  `-Width` parameter to your `Out-File` call.

Answer (score 2):

Instead you can use the command below if you want to see the information only on console

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -User username | format-list
```

or collect the output to a csv file

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -User username | export-csv c:\test.csv -notype -force
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for your reference, select the needed column using select query and pipe it the out-file/export-csv values and out to csv/txt file.

```
Get-Process | select id,ProcessName | Format-Table | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\vinod\De
sktop\AI\process.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

```
... | Out-GridView <# Works only in Powershell ISE #>
```

Gives you Excel-like data grid wih basic search and filters. Can be `CTRL+A`, `CTRL+C` copied to Excel (without headers). **Works only in Powershell ISE**

---

```
... | Export-Csv -LiteralPath 'c:\File.csv' -Encoding UTF32 -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```

Gives you CSV file that is easily opened by Excel ( the magic of UTF32 and "`t" delimeters ). No need to make "Text to columns"

---

```
... | Format-Table -Autosize
```

gives you a table

---

```
... | Format-List
```

gives you multiline output

---

```
... | Select @( 'User', 'AccessRights', '*count*' ) | ...
```

Gives you ability to select only fields you need ( this is typed immediately before output function like `Get-Mailbox | Select @('User', 'AccessRights') | Out-GridView`

---

```
... | Foreach-Object {
    $local:color = 'Green'
    if ( -not $_.Enabled) { $local:color = 'Yellow' }
    Write-Host "Username: $($_.samaccountname)" -f $local:color
    Write-Host "Enabled: $($_.Enabled)" -f $local:color
    ...
}
```

Your own scriptblock gives you output freedom ;)